# Value is not getting after if block Using let keyword

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following code,

```js
let firstData = []

if (id) {
  const {
    data: firstData
  } = usedata(
    buyingSessionGroupId
  )
  firstData =
    firstData?.getdata?.datavalue ? ? []

  console.log("Data is ->", firstData)
}

console.log("Data are ->", firstData)
```

Now here logs are there in case of first block but after that in second it gives `[]`. yes it is because of the let is a block scoped . So,
Can any one help me with this ? Don't want to use the `var`

Comment: While you can fiddle with the destructuring, I think it'd make much more sense just to assign to `firstData` with `=` instead

Comment: I did not got .. Could you please add as an answer

Comment: See the linked canonical to see how to do the destructuring, not that you should do it

Comment: Did you try to run this code in a console? I suspect the problem is in line: `firstData =
    firstData?.getdata?.datavalue ? ? []`